# NSIS uninstaller

Tags: nsis, uninstallation

Have some problems with NSIS uninstall code.

```
RMDir /r "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
```

In Windows 7 this code uninstall files from the folder, but don't uninstall the folder in Start Menu.

In Windows XP this code don't uninstall anything. It's just don't work.

Comment: Post some more code please...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you aren't trying to RMDir the current working directory.

From the NSIS Documentation:

> Note that the current working directory can not be deleted. The
>   current working directory is set by SetOutPath. For example, the
>   following example will not delete the directory.

```
SetOutPath $TEMP\dir
RMDir $TEMP\dir
```

Comment: I am not trying to RMDir the current working directory. This is Start menu directory.

Answer (score 0):

Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\shortcut.lnk"     -if u have any shortcut links
RMDir "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME} "  -to remove the product entry from start menu

Delete all the sub entries like shortcuts first and then go for RMDir.